# ssl_error_log apache issue

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, proxy, httpd

https://localhost works but https://ipaddress didn't

cat logs/ssl_error_log

```
[Mon Aug 02 19:04:11 2010] [error] [client 192.168.1.158] (13)Permission denied: access to /ajaxterm denied
[root@space httpd]# cat logs/ssl_access_log
192.168.1.158 - - [02/Aug/2010:19:04:11 +0530] "GET /ajaxterm HTTP/1.1" 403 290
[root@space httpd]# cat logs/ssl_request_log
[02/Aug/2010:19:04:11 +0530] 192.168.1.158 SSLv3 DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA "GET /ajaxterm HTTP/1.1" 290
```

### httpd.conf file

```
NameVirtualHost *:443
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName localhost
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/ca.key

    <Directory  /usr/share/ajaxterm >
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
        Allow from All
        </Directory>
        DocumentRoot  /usr/share/ajaxterm
    DirectoryIndex ajaxterm.html

       ProxyRequests Off
       <Proxy *>
#               Order deny,allow
               Allow from all
       </Proxy>
       ProxyPass /ajaxterm/ http://localhost:8022/
       ProxyPassReverse /ajaxterm/ http://localhost:8022/

    ErrorLog error_log.log
    TransferLog access_log.log
</VirtualHost>
```

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

Change your **Order** directives to be

```
Order deny,allow
```

And that's it. No other lines. Take out the **Allow from** lines. You can tune those later.

If that does not help, you might have something else blocking the access around your httpd.conf.

Comment: in the <Directory> section you want me to align the "Order" directive? Or you want to uncomment "Order" directive?Thanks.

Comment: In both <Directory> and <Proxy> sections make it ONLY contain the Order directive (being Order deny,allow) and comment out the Allow lines.

Comment: oops ..no luck . I changed it and commented out Allow line ..even that didn't help :(

Comment: Perhaps you have SELinux enabled and it's doing the blocking? Try command getenforce and if it returns enforcing, enter setenforce 0.

Comment: getenforce says SELinux is disabled.Is there is anything else I need check for example file permission and file owners ?
ls -l /usr/share/ajaxterm/
total 292
-rwxr--r-- 1 apache apache  1557 2009-07-24 20:33 ajaxterm.css
-rwxr--r-- 1 apache apache  1963 2010-07-25 19:26 ajaxterm.html
-rwxr--r-- 1 apache apache  8565 2010-07-24 00:43 ajaxterm.js

Comment: Just for completeness, what about ls -lad /usr/share/ajaxterm ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi please do change in following lines

```
Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
        Allow from All
```

It will working after these changes in apache configuration files